# How do I use `TabList` with no selected tab?

Tags: material-ui, tabs

I’m using [`TabList`](https://mui.com/api/tab-list/) (`@mui/lab/TabList`) and want the list to render (initially) *without* any tab selected. How do I achieve this? With the (non-experimental) `Tabs` component, I could do this using the `value` prop with `false` as the value, but `TabList` doesn’t seem to inherit this prop ([ref](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-lab/src/TabList/TabList.d.ts#L15)). Instead, the current value is taken from the `TabContext`, but it is typed to only allow `string` and *not* `false` ([ref](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-lab/src/TabContext/TabContext.d.ts#L16)).

Answer (score -1):

When using the experimental TabList, you set the value on the TabContext level, above the TabList. You need to have a state variable that will hold the value, and you can initialize it with any value you want, like so:

```
const [ tab, setTab ] = useState("1");

return <Box  sx={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <Box> Project <b>{project.name}</b></Box>
        <TabContext value={tab}>
            <TabList>
                <Tab label="Selected Tab" value="1" />
            </TabList>
            <TabPanel value="1">
            </TabPanel>
        </TabContext>
```

if you set the value to false (or any other value that is not present in the list) no tab will be selected